Can't fetch file on a Synology NAS from NextJS serverside
I'm encountering an issue when trying to fetch data from my Next.js app. The data I want to retrieve is located in my NAS Synology device. When I make the fetch request from the NextJS app on the server side, I receive a Connect Timeout Error while the same request works fine with a curl or in my browser.
Here's the error message I'm getting:
⨯ unhandledRejection: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8522:28)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8480:50
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8511:13)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
      at process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'

Could someone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
